# Get id of elements where the ids are dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have a set of elements that have been generated dynamically through Handlebars as seen below

```
         {{#floor as |room i|}}
            <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" >
              <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="{{id}}">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> {{name}}
              </label>
            </div>
         {{/floor}}
```

As you can see, the elements are created with id="{{id}}". But when the page finishes loading, I want to hide these elements until a user clicks a button. I'm finding it hard to get the dynamic ids

Currently, I'm using JQuery as seen below

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#{{id}}').hide();
    });
```

this works with known ids, but not in this case where I don't know the id

Comment: Put a common class on all the elements instead. Avoid putting `id` attributes in repeated/dynamically generated content.

Comment: You can also hide elements by class using JQuery, or do you want the ID?

Comment: `.btn-group-toggle .btn { display: none }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide the element you can also select a unique class.

```
      {#floor as |room i|}}
        <div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" >
          <label class="btn btn-secondary unique-class" id="{{id}}">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> {{name}}
          </label>
        </div>
     {{/floor}}
```

Using JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.unique-class').hide();
});
```

Comment: Why replace an unique identifier with a unique class? And why is `unique-class` in your example not unique?

Comment: What do you mean?